# Стоит ли для связки SQLAlhemy + django использовать aldjemy?

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlalchemy

Или как и советуют в Вики использовать один из совместимых веб-фреймворков
TurboGears, Pylons, Pyramid, Zope ?

Нужен совет гуру.

Comment: А зачем Вам вообще такая связка? Думаю, не стоит. У `Django` свой `ORM`, которым разработчики и пользуются. Обычно, `SQLAlchemy` используют с `Flask`.

Comment: Спасибо,  учту. Но планируется проект масштабируемый с выходом на базы,  обработку которых упрощенный Django ORM не потянет. И от Django так просто отказаться не хочется.  Под него много наработано. Поэтому такой вопрос лучше прояснить заранее,  чем потом тратить дополнительное время и силы.

Answer (score 0):

Есть всегда нативный язык, для решения всяких нестандартных задач и плюм ко всему сам Джанго все так же отправляет запросы в SQL где то на нижнем уровне.
Можно откопать модель более низкого уровня и прописать запрос через нее.
Здесь описывается что-то подобное: https://metanit.com/python/django/5.18.php
пример:

from django.db import connection

class PsychologistOwnTestsListAPIView(APIView):

```
def get(self, request):

    psy_id = request.query_params['psy_id']
    sort_by ='test_id'
    limit = 20
    offset = 0

    try:
        sort_by = request.query_params['sort_by']
    except:
        pass
    
    sql = (
        f"SELECT pst.psychologist_id psy_id, pst.valid_from as valid_from, pst.valid_to as valid_to, pst.id id, t.name, t.id as test_id, t.type as type "
        f"FROM psychologists_tests as pst "
        f"LEFT JOIN tests as  t ON pst.test_id = t.id "
        f"WHERE pst.psychologist_id = {psy_id} "  
        f"ORDER BY {sort_by}"
           )
    data_list = []
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql)  # "SELECT * FROM psychologists_tests WHERE psychologist_id = 4")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()  # получаем все строки
        for row in rows:
            data_row = {
                'psy_id': row[0],
                'valid_from': row[1],
                'valid_to': row[2],
                'psy_test_id': row[3],
                'name': row[4],
                'test_id': row[5],
                'type': row[6],
            }
            data_list.append(data_row)

    return Response({
        'count': len(data_list),
        'results': data_list,
    })
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)